# Org cdlatex doesn't work

Tags: org-mode, latex

I would like to use org to type my math lessons, documentation says it has an embedded system completion which can be activated by :

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'turn-on-org-cdlatex)
```

This command is not present on my system (emacs 24).
There is still an `org-cdlatex-mod` but when I trigger it with `M-x` it says

`Cannot open load file: no such file or directory, cdlatex`

After what if I retrigger the mod it says that the mode is now disabled. However it doesn't do anything after I type `C-c {` to insert an environnment template...

There is a package, but the documentation says that I shouldn't use it since it's embedded in emacs.

Comment: I'm having your same problem! [emacswiki.org](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CDLaTeX) says to download a script written by Carsten Dominik himself from [this link](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/c.dominik/Tools/cdlatex/cdlatex.el), but where to put it in a Windows 7 machine? `C:\home\.emacs.d\???`

Comment: [This other page](https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/cdlatex) says to give the following command: `M-x package-install [RET] cdlatex [RET]`. I've tried, but emacs says `[No match]`. So back to problem #1 -- where to put the script **cdlatex-4.0.el**?

Comment: You can put it anywhere in the file system. The only restriction is that the directory must be in the list of `load-path`. Of course it must also be readable for emacs. Furthermore, I assume that you should rename `cdlatex-4.0.el` to `cdlatex.el`. But the latter is just a guess.

Comment: But the wiki saiy not to install cdlatex because it is now built in.

Comment: @Tobias is right. Type `C-h v RET load-path RET` to get list of all _load-paths_ where to choose from. I chose to put *cdlatex.el* in `C:\Program Files\emacs-24.4\share\emacs\24.4\lisp` from the list of possible load paths, then restarted the machine. In Org-mode activate CDLaTeX with `M-x org-cdlatex-mode` and try inserting some math etc. I'm having some extra trouble with the backquote symbol, I'm getting error msg "_Wrong type argument: characterp, 134217782_", don't know why. If CDLaTeX is off, backquote is all right. Can anyone suggest a fix up?

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar (possibly the same problem) by installing auctex, like this:

```
M-x package-install RET auctex RET
```

I suppose that there is a dependency that both cdlatex and auctex need but which was not installed with cdlatex.